# NativeScript error. More than one view found in list template

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I had such ListView

```
<ListView [items]="groceryList" row="1" class="small-spacing" [class.visible]="listLoaded">
    <template let-item="item" columns="*, auto" >
      <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>      
    </template>
  </ListView>
```

I want to add image button. So I just added `columns="*, auto"` to `template` and 
`col="0"` to Label and `col="1"` to my `Image`

```
 <ListView [items]="groceryList" row="1" class="small-spacing" [class.visible]="listLoaded">
    <template let-item="item" columns="*, auto" >
      <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing" col="0"></Label>
      <Image src="res://delete" (tap)="delete(item.id)" col="1"></Image>      
    </template>
  </ListView>
```

After running an emulator I am getting an error:

[image]

Any thoughts why is that happening and how to fix that?

Comment: You should add `StackLayout` or `GridLayout ` for main container inside the `ListView` template and inside the `Layout` to add the `Image` and the `Label`. For example `<StackLayout><Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing" ></Label>
      <Image src="res://delete" (tap)="delete(item.id)"></Image></StackLayout>`

Comment: @NikolayTsonev should I take out `template` ?

Comment: You do not have to remove the `template `, you should add the Layout inside of it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only one element allowed innside `<template>`, you have two. 
Add a single GridLayout innside the `<template>` instead, then add you elements there.