# Nativescript : Error: More than one view found in list template! Nesting level: 0

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

[The layout inside template solution doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241716/nativescript-error-more-than-one-view-found-in-list-template)

**list.html**

```
<ActionBar title="View Team Members">
    <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout>
    <ListView [items]="teamList" class="small-spacing">
        <template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout>
              <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
              <Label [text]="item.email" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Same error trace  :

> ```
> com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
> Calling js method getView failed
>
> Error: More than one view found in list template! Nesting level: 0
> File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.finlyng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js,
> ```
>
> line: 138, column: 8
>
> ```
> StackTrace: 
>   Frame: function:'getSingleViewRecursive', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.finlyng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js',
> ```
>
> line: 138, column: 15
>         Frame: function:'getSingleViewFromViewRef', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.finlyng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js',
>   line: 154, column: 12
>         Frame: function:'ListViewComponent.onItemLoading', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.finlyng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js',
>   line: 72, column: 25
>         Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.finlyng/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js',
>   line: 146, column: 32
>         Frame: function:'ListViewAdap

Comment: Make sure you have saved your file (when wrapped in Stack layout) and then rebuild the app. Indeed you can have only a root element for your item-template and the error should not be present with the existing structure - basic example here :https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/ui-category/listview/creating-listview/creating-listview.component.html

Comment: @NickIliev saved and re built , the error still exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but I had a similar issue.

I fixed it by nesting the Labels inside a GridLayout. Something like this in my case:

```
<GridLayout rows="auto, *">
  <ListView [items]="newsList" row="1" class="news">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
      <GridLayout rows="auto, *">
        <Image [src]="item.image"></Image>
        <Label [text]="item.title" class="news__item"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```